# Unable to update RecyclerView in intent after onPostExecute from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-asynctask

I am attempting to update a RecyclerView after an HTTP request is made. With the code in the gists below, I am able to open the android activity, render a blank RecyclerView, and get the data from the HTTP Request. I am unable to update the RecyclerView with the data from the HTTP Request.

Below are links the two classes in question for the data

[ItemSelection.java](https://gist.github.com/SomeNerdNamedSteve/98f897dcd77eaad95465ecc9388e8a9b)

[ItemSelectionAdapter.java](https://gist.github.com/SomeNerdNamedSteve/65ce64c8e6b0773760f0299cfa7759fc)

Currently, nothing shows up in the RecyclerView after the HTTP Response is received even though I have the data. How would I populate the RecyclerView after the HTTP response?

Comment: Please don't just link to your code off-site. You need to provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you are missing the list items count in the adapter view please update the below method in your ItemSelectionAdapter

```
 @Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return data.size();
}
```

might it can help you to resolve your issue and another thing is that your are setting adapter to recycle view in post execute method so no need to called method after set adapter

```
 adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

it is not required called the above line after set new adapter to recycle view

Answer (score 1):

You are doing wrong basically, as you are creating Recyclerview in onPostExecute which is bad practice rather than do  like this

Call AsyncTask Like this

```
 public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    // RecyclerView
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter rvAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager rvLayoutManger;
    List<NewsData> news_list;

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        news_list = new ArrayList<NewsData>();
    }


    @Nullable
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_home, null);

        // RecyclerView Setup
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);
        rvLayoutManger = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(rvLayoutManger);
        rvAdapter = new HomeRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), news_list);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);


        load_data_from_server(0);

        return view;
    }

    private void load_data_from_server(int id) {
        AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> task = new AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                Request request = new Request.Builder().url("http://here is my url ").build();
                try {
                    Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(response.body().toString());

                    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);

                        NewsData data = new NewsData(object.getInt("id"), object.getString("title"), object.getString("describtion"));
                        news_list.add(data);

                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.out.print("End of  content");
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };

        task.execute(id);
    }
```

Pass Data in Object Class

```
public class NewsData {

private int id;
private String title, describtion;

public NewsData(int id, String title, String describtion){
    this.id = id;
    this.title = title;
    this.describtion = describtion;
}


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}

public void  setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}

public String getDescribtion(){
    return describtion;
}

public void setDescribtion(String describtion) {
    this.describtion = describtion;
}
```

See Adapter will get data from above define adapter setting with arraylist consist of data

```
rvAdapter = new HomeRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(), news_list);
```